# SQL Split 2 fields into rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I have a row of data that looks like this:

```
200,500,1000 | 50,100,200 | TUA03 | 2019-02-21
```

From the following query.

```
select distinct 
    tbl.qualifier_value,
    tbl.h_discount_val,
    tbl.longlist_mm_text,
    tbl.p_start_date 
from @HoldingTable tbl
```

I need to split the first two fields into new corresponding rows. To give the following output.

```
200 | 50 | TUA03 | 2019-02-21
500 | 100 | TUA03 | 2019-02-21
1000 | 200 | TUA03 | 2019-02-21
```

I can get the first field split like such:

```
select distinct 
    s.Item,
    tbl.h_discount_val,
    tbl.longlist_mm_text,
    tbl.p_start_date
from @HoldingTable tbl
outer apply [dbo].[Split](qualifier_value, ',') s
```

Which gives:

```
1000 |  50,100,200 | TUA03 | 2019-02-21
200  |  50,100,200 | TUA03 | 2019-02-21
500  |  50,100,200 | TUA03 | 2019-02-21
```

I now need to also split the second field but carefully bind the position to the correct position from the first column. By outer applying the same idea with the the second field, I get 9 rows back but I cannot match which second field value is matched from the first field value position.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method is a recursive CTE.  I'm a little unclear on what the column names so I made them generic:

```
with cte as (
      select left(col1, charindex(',', col1) - 1) as col1,
             left(col2, charindex(',', col2) - 1) as col2,
             col3, col4,
             stuff(col1, 1, charindex(',', col1), '') as col1_rest,
             stuff(col2, 1, charindex(',', col2), '') as col2_rest
      from t
      union all
      select left(col1_rest, charindex(',', col1_rest + ',') - 1) as col1,
             left(col2_rest, charindex(',', col2_rest + ',') - 1) as col2,
             col3, col4,
             stuff(col1_rest, 1, charindex(',', col1_rest + ','), '') as col1_rest,
             stuff(col2_rest, 1, charindex(',', col2_rest + ','), '') as col2_rest
      from cte
      where col1_rest > ''
     )
select col1, col2, col3, col4
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a7fa86c05c6451fec76dcf034d9cfd85) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This is amazing, I don't think I've seen recursion in SQL queries. Have you got any idea how the performance of similar solutions is on larger datasets?

Comment: Gordon, I have implemented your solution and it is working, much appreciated.

Comment: @Zero . . . For this type of problem (a handful of recursive steps per row using only operations within the row), recursion should be quite reasonable even on large tables.  There are other situations where size would affect performance.